# Which Eclipse IDE Release works with java version "1.3.1_02"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a pc in which i can't download the latest version of JDK 
The JDK"1.3.1_02" is already installed so i have to deal with it, but it's not compatible with the latest realease of eclipse IDE

Comment: Please research before posting https://coderanch.com/mobile/t/104283/Eclipse-Java

Comment: Have a look at this eclipse archive : http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-2.1.3-200403101828/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 2.1 should work as it is mentioned in this post:
https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Plug-in-architecture/plugin_architecture.html

Comment: I'm going to install the Eclipse 2.1 and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If already installed, you need to set path to JDK as HOME variable.
Or search for the folder of java and uninstal it.